# Does FROM_ UNIXTIME (unix_timestamp) support subquery?

Tags: mysql

I am able to run this command on MYSQL

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1395301163);
```

and get the desired output.
But When i try to run this:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(select signuptime from abc where sno=1);
```

it gives me error.I think that  FROM_UNIXTIME() method support only unixtime in int.Is there any way i can convert unix timestamp from my column`(signuptime)` to normal timestamp.

I have this table named abc.
it has three columns:

1.Sno(Bigint)
2.expiry_date(Big_int)-It contains unix_timestamp in bigint.
3.Status(varchar)

It has let's say 2 rows

**1row**   S.no-1  ,expirydate-1395301163 and status=ACTIVE.

**2ndrow** S.no-2  ,expirydate-1195301203 and status=ACTIVE.

So now i am want a query which compare expirydate of all rows with currentdate and if expirydate is less than current date `update status to inactive`.

Comment: What is the datatype of `signuptime`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a `SELECT` query as an expression, you need another set of parentheses:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME((select signuptime from abc where sno=1));
```

For your second question, you need to do:

```
UPDATE abc
SET Status = 'inactive'
WHERE expiry_date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());
```

Comment: Does that mean every time i use a subquery then i have to use another set of parenthesis

Comment: When you use it as the argument to a function. The first parentheses is for the function, the second is to turn the subquery into an expression.

Comment: Sorry can't post the code due to some reasons  but the problem i am facing is i have a table called advertisement in my database and it has expiry_date column in unix_timestamp.i am using mysql event scheduler to comare unix timestamp by current date and deactivate that advertisement when unixtimestampdate is less than current date.I am using event query from [this](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/10/mysql-event-scheduler.html) page.

Comment: What's the problem you're having? If you can't post code, it's going to be hard for me to figure out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Did you understand what am i trying to acheive?

Comment: Wow that was so easy man how did you do that i was stuck on this problem from last 5 hours.Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use as

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(signuptime) from abc where sno=1 ;
```

Comment: Is there a way by writing only one query i could get timestamp of all rows in my table

Comment: please provide some sample data and desired result this will help us to provide a better solution.

Comment: Sorry can't post the code but the problem i am facing is i have a table called advertisement in my database and it has expiry_date column in unix_timestamp.i am using mysql event scheduler to comare unix timestamp by current date and deactivate that advertisement when unixtimestampdate is less than current date.I am using event query from [this](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/10/mysql-event-scheduler.html) page.

Comment: Not sure I understand it, if you want to select all rows from a table and some column having timestamp then you can use `select FROM_UNIXTIME(col1),col2,col3...from table` also if there are other col with timestamp then just can use the function FROM_UNIXTIME on select.

Comment: Did you understand what am i trying to acheive?

Comment: @Fresher check answer from Barmar , this is exactly what you need to do.